# How to Screenshot NSView for Mac OS?

Tags: swift, macos, nsview

I currently have a function that creates a screenshot of the entire window in a Mac application. However, I would like to target a particular view. I know in iOS you can do the following:

```
extension WKWebView {

    var screenshot: UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size).image { _ in
                drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bounds.size), afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
            drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            return image
        }
    }
}
```

How would I convert this to Mac OS using AppKit instead of UIKit. The following is my current computed property for screenshots of the entire window.

```
extension WKWebView {

    var screenshot: NSImage {
        let displayID = CGWindowID() // cgmaindisplayid
        let imageRef = CGDisplayCreateImage(displayID)
        return NSImage(cgImage: imageRef!, size: (NSScreen.main?.frame.size)!)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSView` method `func dataWithPDF(inside rect: NSRect) -> Data`

```
extension NSView {
    var image: NSImage? {
        return NSImage(data: dataWithPDF(inside: bounds))
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this approach won't always work because the image is not rendered without lockFocusing the image

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483797-datawithpdf **This data can be placed on an NSPasteboard object, written to a file, or used to create an NSImage object.**

Comment: Thanks.  If I use your code, though, the image will be created with 72 dpi resolutions on a retina display.

Comment: The data is exactly the same data used to draw your view. There is no loss AFAIK

Comment: My apology...  I was wrong.  I guess it's HEIC that doesn't support a higher resolution beyond 72 dpi.